# What does Gosched() do if a thread is locked with LockOSThread()?

Tags: go

If I call runtime.Gosched() on a thread where I've called runtime.LockOSThread(), what exactly happens?  I can't find good documentation on this.  I presume it is a no-op, but couldn't figure it out for sure.

Comment: Are they at all related? `runtime.Gosched()` yields the so-called "processor" (P) while `runtime.LockOSThread()` binds the currently executing _goroutine_ (G) to the underlying OS thread (M), not to P (see [this](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/) and [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) for the model). Hence I'd speculate that once you run `runtime.Gosched()` the scheduler would probably pick another goroutine from the available runqueues and make the freed P run it. IOW, the fact you've pinned a G to an M merely makes that G always run on _that_ M instead of any available.

Comment: @kostix - the association is bidirectional, at least according to the docs: "The calling goroutine will always execute in that thread, and **no other goroutine will execute in it**" (emphasis added).

Comment: In my eyes, that refers to another property of the scheduler. It tries to make `GOMAXPROCS` goroutines to be running at all times–provided, of course, there are as much or more goroutines in the runqueues,–and that means, that it will eventually create _at least_ `GOMAXPROCS` OS threads. Once a thread becomes "busy" for any reason other than _actively_ running a goroutine (executing code)–the most typical case is performing a longish syscall not involving I/O on a pollable FD (which would have been handled by the netpoller), in which case the scheduler will spawn an extra thread if needed.

Comment: IOW, if you have `GOMAXPROCS` goroutines running on the same number of OS threads, them make them all perform long sleeps in some syscalls roughly at the same time, and by then there will be another `GOMAXPROCS` goroutines ready to run in the runqueues, the scheduler will spawn that many new OS threads to run those goroutines. So, pinning a goroutine to a thread merely means that particular thread will be _mostly_ unavailable to the scheruler–except for the case that particular pinned goroutine is ready to run.

Comment: To explain that from another point of view–the whole idea of pinning is there not to somehow improve scheduling for a goroutine (or give it more CPU time etc); rather, it's there to interoperate with non-Go code which _assumes_ a sequence of calls to it (usually involving some allocated data, maybe even allocated internally by that code) is always performed on the same thread. As an example, GUI frameworks typically expect their "main loop" to be working on a single thread. Pinning a goroutine solves this: when the goroutine runs, it always runs on the pinned thread w/o any extra measures.